# get string after blackslah in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Here's my problem. I want to get `2017` from the string below. I've tried the code below but it doesn't work. I want to use regex but I don't understand the backslash.

Code :

```
$str = explode("\","File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\printing\baryun - cetak transferpaper.tif");
    echo $str[count($str)-5];
```

String :

```
File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\printing\baryun - cetak transferpaper.tif
```

Comment: Inside of double quotes you need double backslashes: `"\\"`

Comment: you want to get only 2017? or some other strings have values other than 2017?

Comment: acctually i want get 2017 september 26, i need it to make to date.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? Explode will do the same thing but faster and with less memory use. https://3v4l.org/rQs0k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match it using `^File=D:\\[a-zA-Z]+\\[a-z]+\\([0-9]{4})`

That is:

```
<?php
   $line = 'File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\printing\baryun - cetak transferpaper.tif';
    $r = "/^File=D:\\\\[a-zA-Z]+\\\\[a-z]+\\\\([0-9]{4})\\\\([a-z]+)\\\\([0-9]{1,2})/";

   if (preg_match($r, $line, $match)) {
      print $match[1];
      }
?>
```

To match the year, month and day, use `^File=D:\\\\[a-zA-Z]+\\\\[a-z]+\\\\([0-9]{4})\\\\([a-z]+)\\\\([0-9]{1,2})`

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 35 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Champion\logtxt.php on line 72

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then you need to "double-backslash" `$line` as such: `$line = "File=D:\\Shared\print\\2017\\september\\26\\printing\\baryun - cetak transferpaper.tif";`

Comment: still not work. u say update the string. but i want get value without do anything to the string.

Comment: Its not working because in PHP you need to also escape backslashes.

Comment: so immposible to get the value "2017" from that string  ?

Comment: or you use single quotes instead of double quotes.Example `$line = 'File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\printing\baryun - cetak transferpaper.tif';`

Comment: If your string is coming from a text file or somewhere else(i.e not hardcoded) you can use the str_replace function to replace every \ with \\

Comment: Try the code in my answer. It should work. Just copy and paste it.

Comment: <?php
     $line = 'File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\printing\baryun - cetak transferpaper.tif';

     if (preg_match('/^File=D:\\[a-zA-Z]+\\[a-z]+\\([0-9]{4})\\([a-z]+)\\([0-9]{1,2})/i', $line, $match)) {
        print $match[1];
       }
?>

Comment: You didnt use my updated code. Use the updated code in my answer. Seems you're still using the code from my initial answer

Comment: oh yea, now get the 2017. thanks. to get month and day should i add the regex ?